# Jquery popup window not rendering the values as expected

Tags: jquery, jsp, liferay

In my life ray application I need to display a popup window with some value generated from back-end and available at session.

The requirement is from the current page I have to I will get an input value and using this value I have to generate output value and display it in a popup window.

Please see my JQuery code

```
jQuery('#searchLink').click(function() {
    jQuery('#empSearchInput').submit(); 
    window.open("/o/consumer/jsp/popup.jsp",null,
    "height=200,width=400,status=yes,toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no");

});
```

jQuery('#empSearchInput').submit();  this will invoke the back-end function and generate output value and set it in the current session,but inside the popup window it is not displaying,I believe that the popup window rendered before completing the back-end call.Help me

Comment: Yes, popup window has been rendered in browser by the time your back end call is submitting. You need to pass the backend data in callback of submit. Ideally open the window in submit callback. $( "form" ).on( "submit", function( event ) {
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log( $( this ).serialize() );
});

Comment: I have changed the code to this ,but nothing happend.jQuery('#searchLink').click(function() {
doFormsubmission();});
 
 function doFormsubmission()
 {
  alert(12)
  jQuery("#empSearchInput").submit(function() {
  jQuery.ajax({
           type: 'POST',
           url: jQuery(this).attr('action'),
           data: jQuery(this).serialize(),
           success: function(data) {
           window.open("/o/consumer/jsp/popup.jsp",null,
     "height=200,width=400,status=yes,toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no");
           }
         });
         return false;
       });

Comment: Can you try putting your alert inside success and make sure your server is returning success. Try using following code and confirm if you are getting alert .. function doFormsubmission() { 
  jQuery("#empSearchInput").submit(function() { 
   jQuery.ajax({ 
    type: 'POST',
    url: jQuery(this).attr('action'),
    data: jQuery(this).serialize(),
    success: function(data) {        
    alert(12);
    window.open("/o/consumer/jsp/popup.jsp",null, "height=200,width=400,status=yes,toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no"); 
   } 
  });
 return false; 
  }); 
}